# How to find same keys and values in HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, key

I have an HashMap with names(key) and dates(value) and I need to show if a name that i enter again is a duplicate (I am doing socket programming with different states). Example, I put in the map 3 different names and at the forth time I put a duplicate name.

I tried these codes (they run) but with no success:

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

if(stat.equals("RECEIVE_NAME")){
   name = reader.readLine();
   if(map.containsKey(name)){
      System.out.println("duplicate");
   }
}
```

or

```
for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()){
   if(name.equals(entry.getKey())){
      sendMessage("duplicate");
   }
}
```

NB: **I have a map.put(name)** when is not a duplicate after this sequence of blocks. And i know that an hash map can not have duplicate keys :)

Comment: how can you match any keys in your map when the map is empty? You show us code where you create a brand new map which will contain no keys. perhaps make sure the map you are using has a size greater than 0 before checking for duplicates

Comment: A `HashMap` can't have duplicate keys.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#putIfAbsent-K-V- if more threads can insert then use concurrent version

Comment: Your first solution should work.   You should try a debugger, and make sure that the name is exactly the same.  Watch out for spaces. You might try using "name=reader.readLine().trim().

Answer (score 0):

A HashMap cannot contain duplicate keys. If you put a key-value pair in a map which already contains the key, the old value will be replaced by the new value.

Comment: Yes, i got it. I just want to understand how can i get a String saying "DUPLICATE" if what i am trying to put as key already exist.

Comment: Okay, I see. In that case, your first solution should work. Verify that the variable `name` is exactly the same as the existing key in the map. Pay close attention to any whitespace. It has to be exact.

Answer (score 0):

`map.put()` returns the previous value associated with key, or null if there was no mapping for key. So you can store that return value and check if is not null:

```
String check = map.put(name);
if(check != null){
    System.out.println("dup: " + check);
}
```

Use `map.putIfAbsent(name)` to not overwrite the associated value.